# MongoDB creates a composite index that contains text indexes

Tags: mongodb

Already indexed

> db.h.createIndex({'name':1})
>
> db.h.createIndex({'addre':'text'})

Now I created a composite index:

> db.h.createIndex({'name':1,'age':1,'tel':1,'addre':'text'})

But it did not work. Error message:

> "errmsg" : "only one text index per collection allowed, found existing text index \"addre_text\""

So how should I create such a composite index?

Comment: The error message is telling the truth; you simply can't create more than one index that contains a text index per collection.

Comment: @JohnnyHK OK，thx